# C++ Question about Boost UBLAS

Tags: c++, boost, ublas

Does the Boost UBLAS library have a built-in solver for solving systems of equations?  The documentation implies that all the ublas solver routines require the matrix to already be in triangular form.

But, if a matrix is not in triangular form, is there anything in ublas that can reduce the matrix and then back-substitute, to solve a system of equations?

Answer (score 4):

LU decomposition

Comment: Doesn't LU decomposition require the matrices to be triangular?

Comment: No, it's by definition decomposition _into_ triangular matrices. Then they can be solved by triangular solver. I don't remember ublas syntax for it - it was quite messy - but idea is the same: decompose, then use triangular solver.